# signup angularjs controller not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm creating my first controller in angularjs, however i can't seem to make it call the `register` function, since none of the console.log message is being printed. i've set the button to type `submit` and then in form i'm calling `ng-submit="vm.register()"`. However no message not even error in the console?

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-5" ng-app="KryptoApp" ng-controller="RegisterController">
    <form id="sign_up" ng-submit="vm.register()" novalidate>
        <div class="box_form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="Din email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Brugernavn</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" placeholder="Dit brugernavn">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Adgangskode</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password1" placeholder="Din adgangskode">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Adgangskode bekræftelse</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password2" placeholder="Bekræft din adgangskode">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox-holder text-left">
                <div class="checkbox_2">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="accept" id="check_2" name="check">
                    <label for="check_2">
                        <span>I Agree to the
                            <strong>Terms &amp; Conditions</strong>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center add_top_30">
                <button class="btn_1" id="sign_up_btn" type="submit">Opret</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('KryptoApp')
      .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];


    function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.register = register;


      function register() {
        Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password1, vm.password2, vm.username);
        console.log('test');
      }
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **`controller as`** syntax

```
div class="col-md-5" ng-app="KryptoApp" ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">
```